# How can I dry out a soggy floor in my kitchen?

Tags: flooring

some wooden floorboard in my kitchen got some water that had not been cleaned up for an hour and the timber seems to have absorbed some of the water and make a soggy sound when walked over.

how can I dry it out pls?

---

thanks guys for the answers, the thing is I am in London and not sure I can rent a shop vac anywhere close.

so a normal table fan is of no use ?

it is a purpose built first floor flat...with underfloor heating...I am tried turning on heating for a while but has not helped. think the wood had absorbed a lot of water..the thing is the spilled water is just a small bucket left for just 30 mins or so, so I am surprised it has become this severe.

in London it is very hot these days so door and windows are open meaning good ventilation, but things hv not helped and actually I think water is seeping along the floor board and coming into the living room. so I need to act fast.

this is the picture..if u zoom in u can see the water seeping out..and the sogginess seems to be spreading to other areas as well..so appreciate quick help.
thanks
[image]

and this is video..
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OfZVd6k_m6s

about 2-3 liters of water spilled in the affected area near the kitchen which was mopped out after 30 mins. But even after trying to dry out for two days it has not helped and in fact it is spreading to other areas..any advice, please ?

Comment: thanks what other info u need pls ? it is a laminated wooden floor. I tried a table fan directed at it..but not helped..just a small section of the kitchen this affects..it is a purpose built flat..let me know any other info u need..tks

Comment: If it's laminated wood and not a composite, and the water didn't cause the layers to delaminate, it will eventually dry out and return to normal.  However, total drying could take months if water wicked into seams and was absorbed into the wood.

Comment: this some boards are getting warped..and when steping on to this section, its feels bit like stepping into a soggy field. I also can see water seeping out when stepped on..amazing as it was just a small bucket of water left for possibly 30 mins that caused this..any quick way to dry this out pls..

Comment: Not sure why this got the final close vote. There's plenty of information up there.

Comment: Look at the edit history @isherwood

Comment: The edits all occurred before the final close vote.

Answer (score 2):

You could pick up a dehumidifier and set it up in your kitchen. That will allow you to control the moisture level and speed up drying time.

Comment: Had a water leak in a previous apartment, and this is the best course of action. You can rent large industrial sized units which might be best. The water may leave stains in the wood, but a dehumidifier is the best bet for getting it dried out.

Answer (score 2):

The only way you'll dry things out quickly is to disassemble the floor. Depending on your carpentry skills and the nature of the room, this may be a fairly painless task. Without photos or a clearer description I can't offer specific advice, but it usually involves removing base shoe and lifting each row out as it was put together.

Otherwise, sop up what you can with towels and run plenty of fans. Airflow is key, and if you're able to keep the relative humidity down in the home, do so. Evaporation is much quicker if the dew point is low.

Comment: A regular box fan will not do much. You need to rent a high velocity drying fan that directs the air through a duct close to the floor. If you have a shop vac, you can vacuum at the joints. This will pull a lot of water out.

Comment: Even box fans are many times better than no fans, though. As long as there's circulation in the room, evaporation can occur at a much faster rate. I've seen it with drywall many times, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Use a shop vac with the crevice tool on every joint you can get to. There is a specific tool for water pick-up on a flat floor. Try that. Then take the tool off and let the vac hold the hose to a joint for 15 min and periodically change to a different location.

Comment: If you don't have access to a shop vac, try any sort of wet vacuum (such as a carpet cleaning machine).  You might even be able to get a professional carpet cleaning company to come extract some of the water.